# Laravel Nova 4 format date in BelongsTo field

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-nova

I kindly need your support to understand how to apply the same date format, as indicated in the original resource, to the `belongsTo` field in Laravel Nova 4.

**Resource 1**

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make('id')->sortable(),

        Date::make('Shipment Eta Date')
            ->rules('required', 'date')
            ->placeholder('Shipment Eta Date')
            ->displayUsing(fn ($value) => $value ? $value->format('D d/m/Y') : ''),

        HasMany::make('ShipmentInfos', 'shipmentInfos'),
    ];
}
```

**Resource 2**

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make('id')->sortable(),

        Date::make('Shipment Sent Date')
            ->rules('required', 'date')
            ->placeholder('Shipment Sent Date')
            ->displayUsing(fn ($value) => $value ? $value->format('D d/m/Y') : ''),

        HasMany::make('ShipmentInfos', 'shipmentInfos'),
    ];
```

**Resource 3**

```
BelongsTo::make('ShipmentSentDate', 'shipmentSentDate'),
BelongsTo::make('ShipmentEtaDate', 'shipmentEtaDate'),
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
BelongsTo::make('ShipmentSentDate', 'shipmentSentDate')
    ->displayUsing(fn ($value) => $value ? $value->format('D d/m/Y') : ''),
            
BelongsTo::make('ShipmentEtaDate', 'shipmentEtaDate')
    ->displayUsing(fn ($value) => $value ? $value->format('D d/m/Y') : ''),
```

Comment: try this but with your format
->displayUsing(function ($item) {
                return Carbon::parse($item)->format('Y-m-d');
            })

Comment: @Harris
you've helped me too much. .. here is the solution :

            BelongsTo::make('ShipmentSentDate', 'shipmentSentDate')
                ->displayUsing(function ($shipmentSentDate) {
                    return Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
                }),

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the inconvenience, and I would like to thank @Harris and @Karl Hill. Here's the solution:

```php
BelongsTo::make('ShipmentSentDate', 'shipmentSentDate')
    ->displayUsing(function ($shipmentSentDate) {
        return Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    }),
```

Thank you.